# Can't store output of SystemVerilog module in 2D array

Tags: arrays, verilog, system-verilog

I have a SystemVerilog module **mFunc** described as follows:

```
module mFunc #(parameter N = 1, parameter W=1)
        (input logic signed [W:0] x[N],
         output logic signed [W:0] Cx[N]);

always_comb 
  for(int k=0; k<N; k++)
    Cx[k] = N-x[k];

endmodule: mFunc
```

and a module **mFunc2** which calls **mFunc**:

```
module mFunc2 #(parameter N = 1, parameter W=1)
         (input logic signed [W:0] x[N][N],
          output logic signed [W:0] Cx[N][N]);

logic signed [W:0] x_rows[N];
logic signed [W:0] C_rows[N]; 

mFunc #(.N(N), .W(W)) mFunc_rows(.x(x_rows), .Cx(C_rows));

always_comb begin
  for(int k=0; k<N; k++) begin
    for(int j=0; j<N; j++)begin
      x_rows[j] = x[k][j];
      Cx[k][j] = C_rows[j]; 
    end
  end 
end

endmodule: mFunc2
```

When I run simulation the behavior of the module is according to figure 1 and the output (**C_rows**) of **mFunc** is not stored properly in **Cx**, saving just the last value of **C_rows** as can be seen in Figure 1.

Please could anyone help me with this problem?

[Figure 1: Statement of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cS2LL.png)

Here is the link of the simulation in [EDA Playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/2pQb)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing only the last row filling the entire matrix is due to how you've implemented the `mFunc2` module. In it, you have combinational logic containing a for loop assigning `Cx[k]` to `C_rows`, which translates into `x_rows` being assigned to the `x[N-1]`. Then, the logic is in the `mFunc` module can convert that `x_rows` into `C_rows` for the `x[N-1]` row. Finally, your combinational logic in `mFunc2` runs again, assigning all rows of `Cx` to that `C_rows`.

Thinking about it from a synthesis prospective, you are only ever instantiating a single `mFunc` module, which means the logic for translating a row from `x` to `Cx` only exists for a single row. As you have no clock or other synchronous mechanisms, you cannot feed a single row into the module and get its result, and then feed in the next row as you are trying to do with the for loop. To have the design work combinationally, you must create enough resources in the design to complete the task. In this case, that means having `N` (as there are `N` rows) `mFunc` modules, one for each row. Otherwise, you can introduce a clock and feed in a single row into `mFunc` every cycle for `N` cycles.

The purely combinational path is relatively easy, as all you need to do to your `mFunc2` module is instantiate more `mFunc` in it. You can do this using a `generate` loop, or you can make use of array modules which work perfectly for your case:

```
module mFunc2 #(parameter N = 1, parameter W=1)
             (input logic signed [W:0] x[N][N],
              output logic signed [W:0] Cx[N][N]);

    // Here, we make use of arrays of modules to make N instantiations of mFunc
    // Note the [N] next to the mFunc_rows, meaning we are declaring an array
    // of mFunc modules, ie N of them. These can be hooked up to the unpacked
    // arrays x and Cx directly and will produce the desired output in Cx
    mFunc #(.N(N), .W(W)) mFunc_rows[N](.x(x), .Cx(Cx));


endmodule: mFunc2
```

Quick side note, if you intend for `W` to be the bit width of the values in `x` and `Cx`, you need to declare them as `logic signed [W-1:0]` not `logic signed [W:0]` as the latter will produce variables of length `W+1`. Example, a byte would be `[7:0]`, not `[8:0]` as it has 8 bits.

Comment: Thank you for the response. How the design would seem if a clock is added to feed each row?

Comment: @joe_cat That would require a bit of work and additional signals for beginning the process and to indicated once the processing is complete. More specifications would be required to design it out. Though, on a basic level, it would require an `always @(posedge clk)` block with a counter to index the current row as well as a memory/registers for storing the calculated `Cx`. It not too hard, but is  a significant change.